# Execute method when other method is called

Tags: php, class, methods, call

Is there any way in PHP how to dynamically call a method of one class when method of another class is called?
An example:
call method

```
User::deleteUser('user_id');
```

But before exetucing this method i would like to prepend call for method:

```
Archive::saveRecord('user_id')
```

I need to have it dynamic as I want to hook it to more methods which are deleting data from tables. The class and method names will be provided in the list available in class Archive.
It is more like an archiving plugin which can be also turned off.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke functions using variables that contain their name. Example:

```
php > function test() { echo 'works!'; }
php > $exec = 'test';
php > $exec();
works!
```

Using this technique you can pass in the name of the next function to invoke or determine it with some other logic.

If you have an array called `$Archive` and want to step through each function listed in this array, you could do something like this:

```
foreach ($Archive AS $func) $func();
```

---

This does work just as well if you need to specify a class:

```
php > class other { function test() { echo 'other.test() called.'; } }
php > function outside($call) { $call(); }
php > outside('other::test');
other.test() called.
```